# Pop Up Button Cell return a boolean using Cocoa Binding

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm working on an `NSTableView` populated by an `NSArrayController` connected to a `Core Data Entity` with a few `boolean` attributes. I'm using `Cocoa Bindings`.

Most cells/columns are using the `NSButtonCell` class, which works great for those boolean attributes. They can be populated by the array and the user can modify them without issues.

However, for one of the columns, I want to give users the option to choose between two items (`Item A`, `Item B`) using a `NSPopUpButtonCell` instead of a checkbox. The value associated with that column is a boolean, so I'm currently getting an error

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key value..

What would be the recommended way to configure that cell so that if the user selects Item A we pass 0, Item B we pass 1; and also populate the cell correctly (Item A or B) using the existing boolean value when the table is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `selectedIndex` instead of `value` for `NSPopUpButtonCell`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSPopUpButtonCell.html for complete list of NSPopUpButtonCell bindings.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much. I overlooked that and was indeed using `value`.